# CommandLine parser for arrays of type enum

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-arguments

We are trying to find a command line parser that can parse array with enums.
CommandlineParser supports parsing arrays with int or string but not enum.
For e.g

```
 [OptionArray("o", "output", HelpText = "The output files to generate.", DefaultValue = new[] { "OptimizeFor.Accuracy", "OptimizeFor.Speed" })]
  public string[] OutputFiles { get; set; }
```

Works fine. But not the below one:

```
 public enum OptimizeFor
        {
            Unspecified,
            Speed,
            Accuracy
        }
    [OptionArray("o", "output", HelpText = "The output files to generate.", DefaultValue = new[] { OptimizeFor.Accuracy, OptimizeFor.Speed })]
    public OptimizeFor[] OutputFiles { get; set; }
```

Comment: You don't ask a question, just stating your intent. Are you asking how to add that functionality to CommandLineParser ? Or whether there are other libraries having this built in ? Or how to build a CommandLineParser of your own ?

Comment: Thanks Matt. I am trying to use existing commandline parser as thought it should be readily available. CommandLineParser does support enums but I haven't seen any example where enum arrays having enums have been used.

Answer (score 2):

here is a patch to command line to parse enum arrays. I have created a pull request. https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline/pull/148

```
    public bool SetValue(IList<string> values, object options)
    {
        var elementType = _property.PropertyType.GetElementType();

        var propertyType = elementType;
        if (propertyType.IsGenericType &&
        propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            propertyType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }

        var array = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, values.Count);

        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (propertyType.BaseType.Equals(typeof (System.Enum)))
                {
                    array.SetValue(Enum.Parse(propertyType, values[i]), i);
                    _property.SetValue(options, array, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    array.SetValue(Convert.ChangeType(values[i], elementType, _parsingCulture), i);
                    _property.SetValue(options, array, null);
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return ReceivedValue = true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this what you're looking for, if so it should get you on the right track.

```
public enum OptimizeFor
{
    Unspecified,
    Speed,
    Accuracy
}

public class EnumParser
{
    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> FindSelected<TEnum>(IEnumerable<string> enumItemNames)
    {
        var selectedOtions = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TEnum))
            .Intersect(enumItemNames, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            .Select(i => Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), i))
            .Cast<TEnum>();
        return selectedOtions;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Some fake arguments
        args = new[] {"-o", "SPEED", "accuracy", "SomethingElse"};

        var selectedEnumVals = EnumParser.FindSelected<OptimizeFor>(args);

        selectedEnumVals.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, after looking at the comments above, I'd definitely looking at one of those libraries.

Comment: Looks like the existing parsers don't support the enum collection. As a workaround I am using string array & converting them to enum in my code.