Limiting command line switch value to specific words (using Nuget CommandLineParser)
I am using the CommandLineParser Nuget package in my project. I am trying to get to grips with the way some of the switches work.
For example:
public class Options
{
    [Option("mode", Required = false, HelpText = "Specifies the import mode. Eg: --mode clm")]
    public string? ImportMode { get; set; }
}

The options are parsed in the normal way:
  var parserResult = Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args);

  parserResult.WithParsed(options => OnSuccessfulParse(options));
  parserResult.WithNotParsed(errs =>
  {
      var helpText = HelpText.AutoBuild(parserResult, h => h, e =>
      {
          return e;
      });
      ReturnErrorCode = ErrorCode.CommandLineArguments;
  });

This switch is limited to specific values:

clm
generic
students

At the moment I am manually checking, post parsing, that the property is not null and that its value is one of those 3.
But, isn't there a way that I can indicate this in my Options class?

Instead of string you can use an enum

@KlausGütter I also have need for enum for another of my switches actually. Please advise! Thanks.

@KlausGütter Are you referring to this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28705891/2287576

That's about enum arrays. A simple enum also works fine, just change the type of ImportMode to an enum type.

I'm not sure that you can limit values of a flag with CommandLineParser but you can use another its feature - Verbs
It allows for multiple sets of options that will be parsed and invoked, corresponding to an input command.
So it can go like this:

[Verb("clm", HelpText = "some help here")]
class ClmOptions { 
}

[Verb("generic", HelpText = "some help here")]
class GenericOptions {
}

[Verb("students", HelpText = "some help here")]
class StudentOptions { 
}

// during invocation
// ...

static int Main(string[] args) {
    Parser.Default.ParseArguments<ClmOptions, GenericOptions, StudentOptions>(args)
    .WithParsed<ClmOptions>(options => ...)
    .WithParsed<GenericOptions>(options => ...)
    .WithParsed<StudentOptions>(options => ...)
    .WithNotParsed(errors => ...)
}

This is sort of what you need, utilizing inheritance, you can make sets of common flags for those commands, so in the end, usage will look like this:
your.exe clm --some-common-flag --some-another-flag

your.exe generic --some-common-flag --some-unique-for-generic-flag


Thanks for your suggestion! But I like the idea that was made in the comments about using an enum. Waiting to hear on that one.

There is some information, do you wnat your modes to be mutually exclusive?

Not sure what you mean really. I have a single switch called mode. And it can have one of 3 values. I’ll look up re. enum link.

The linked enum article did the trick actually. I have adapted that. All as I want now!

If I went with the verbs route then I would need common flags. Eg. A log switch must be provided.  I think I’ll stay with the enum approach now. But I think the way I am going about validating the parsed switches can be improved as I am doing verification multiple times. Different topic. Ultimately I have 4 actions: create, import clm, import generic, import students. And depending on what action it is I will be checking for extra switches like csv, xml etc.

You could have used some kind of BaseOptions with common flags like --log_ that you've mentioned and 4 verbs that inherit from it. With subclasses defining more concrete flags that make sense only to them, I hope that I'm being clear enough :D

I have accepted your answer because I decided to spend some time combining a second console app into this one. And the verbs concept came in handy. So both verbs and enum options are in play.
